# hana simple fold "call to non-constexpr function"

Tags: c++, g++, constexpr, boost-hana

I simplified my code producing an error, and found that even this simple counting function gave me an error (see below):

```
#include <boost/hana/tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/fold.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/plus.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/integral_constant.hpp>

int main() {
    using namespace boost;

    constexpr auto inc = [](auto n, auto el) { return hana::int_c<n> + hana::int_c<1>; };
    constexpr auto count = hana::fold(hana::make_tuple(hana::int_c<3>),
                                      hana::int_<0>{},
                                      inc
    );

    return 0;

}
```

Error (ommitted some that seemed irrelevant):

```
 /usr/local/include/boost/hana/detail/variadic/foldl1.hpp:202:57: error: ‘static constexpr decltype(auto) boost::hana::detail::variadic::foldl1_impl<2u>::apply(F&&, X1&&, X2&&) [with F = const main()::<lambda(auto:1, auto:2)>&; X1 = boost::hana::integral_constant<int, 0>; X2 = boost::hana::integral_constant<int, 3>]’ called in a constant expression
             return foldl1_impl<sizeof...(xn) + 1>::apply(
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
                 static_cast<F&&>(f), static_cast<X1&&>(x1), static_cast<Xn&&>(xn)...
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
             );
             ~                                            
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/hana/fold_left.hpp:18:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/hana/concept/foldable.hpp:19,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/hana/core/to.hpp:16,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/hana/bool.hpp:17,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/hana/tuple.hpp:16,
                 from ...:
/usr/local/include/boost/hana/detail/variadic/foldl1.hpp:31:41: note: ‘static constexpr decltype(auto) boost::hana::detail::variadic::foldl1_impl<2u>::apply(F&&, X1&&, X2&&) [with F = const main()::<lambda(auto:1, auto:2)>&; X1 = boost::hana::integral_constant<int, 0>; X2 = boost::hana::integral_constant<int, 3>]’ is not usable as a constexpr function because:
         static constexpr decltype(auto) apply(F&& f, X1&& x1, X2&& x2) {
                                         ^~~~~
/usr/local/include/boost/hana/detail/variadic/foldl1.hpp:32:39: error: call to non-constexpr function ‘main()::<lambda(auto:1, auto:2)> [with auto:1 = boost::hana::integral_constant<int, 0>; auto:2 = boost::hana::integral_constant<int, 3>]’
             return static_cast<F&&>(f)(static_cast<X1&&>(x1),
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                        static_cast<X2&&>(x2));
```

I used c++17 with g++ 6.3. It looks like it says that the lambda isn't seen as a constexpr, but it looks to me like it uses only constant values. Can anyone suggest to me how I can make this code work? (It's purpose is to count the number of elements in the tuple passed to fold)

Comment: [`[](...) constexpr {...}`](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/P0170R1.pdf)?

Comment: @HenriMenke `error: expected ‘{’ before ‘constexpr’` on g++ 6.3 (works on clang though, but on clang the code I provided works as is)

Comment: _constexpr lambda expressions_ [are only supported since GCC 7](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support).

Comment: Thank you, I'll update to gcc7 now. I hope this also resolves my original problem with `hana::group` (an example from their own documentation)...

Comment: g++ 7 works! Unfortunate that boost's documentation states ["Fully working" for gcc>=6.0.0](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/hana/doc/html/index.html). On clang my original problem still persists, which is weird, but for now my problem is resolved.

Comment: Before GCC 7, you can use functors with constexpr operator().

Answer (score 0):

If your compiler doesn't support constexpr lambdas, you have to write out the closure types yourself (at namespace or class scope, not at function scope since a local class cannot have member templates):

```
constexpr struct inc_t {
    template<class N, class T>
    constexpr auto operator()(N n, T) const { return hana::int_c<n> + hana::int_c<1>; }
} inc;
```

Otherwise, you can still use hana but the result of computations will not be available to the type system.

Comment: Actually there is an error with the parameter `n`. `hana::int_c<n>` should be `n`.

Comment: @O'Neil yes, that would be simpler. `hana::int_c<n>` still works, because `hana::integral_constant` inherits from `std::integral_constant` and so has a constexpr conversion to `int`.

Comment: It's not about the conversion, but the function parameter going into the template parameter.

Comment: @O'Neil that's fine - `n` is a constant expression, so it can be used as a non-type template argument.

Comment: @O'Neil note that `n` is a value of type `hana::integral_constant<int, C>` for some `C`, *not* a value of type `int`.